# 2 Themes in 1 Magento install - How to work on non live theme and view changes

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, frontend

I have a Magento store and i want to change the template. I want to install a 2nd template and be able to work on this 2nd template and be able to view my changes on the front end without customers seeing it. Is there any way of doing this?

Magento 1.9.x

Comment: Can't you work in a local environment ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create a second store `store2` with his store view `store2`, then you fork your theme to another one exemple theme2.
2. You set in admin for the the second store `store2` the new theme `theme2`
3. Now can work on your new template and you'll be able to see your changes, after when its ok you deploy it on your pricipal one.
4. You can access to your new store like this: `www.domaine.com?___store=store2`

**Nb**: If you have a **storeswitcher** in your principal store **(The store switcher appear when you have 2 store views under the current website you are viewing.)**, don't forget to remove the new store on it on customising that file, or you remove the storeswitcher block via xml.